# South African Sound FX?

Tags: recording, sound-effects, south, south-africa

Hey there.
Anyone based in S Africa, or have good recordings from there they'd be willing to trade?
Working on a show based there - could do with some more specific recordings - preferably  crowd bgd street chatter, towns, kids or any rural ambiences specific to S Africa - jo'Berg/Capetown or anywhere really.

Please let me know, I have UK/London specific recordings i could trade.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hey man, My name is Nicols Williams. I'm based in South Africa. I have a few recordings but need to make some more soon anyway. So if you could perhaps be a bit more specific with the sounds you need I can make them more accurate ;) my email address is nclswilliams@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Andrew...I live in Cape Town. Would be up for a trade as well.
I use an H2 Zoom recorder. Let me know if you need anymore sounds. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very large library of SA sounds from all over. Both rural and urban. Lots of different languages as well. All at 24/96 some MS and some stereo. Just let me know what you need and if I don't have it I will get it. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have some Rural + Bush type Atmos recordings, mostly from KZN one or two form JHB. Sennheiser MS/ SD702  192/24. Edited and Labeled. What do you need? Can never have enough Atmos tracks.... an Atmos/Amb Swap-meet sounds like a fine Idea. Cheers!!